# Tomcat server 404s when trying to access my website

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I am trying to make a website to host some of my personal photography. I have purchased access to a VPS using ubuntu. My website uses Spring Boot with a MysSQL database and uses JSPs. I am trying to get my website working using a tomcat server.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the project runs just fine with tomcat on my M2 Macbook, following the same process.

When I try and access my website at *VPSip*:8080/service, I get this error:

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/service/] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Tomcat works fine when I access *VPSip*:8080/.

I have tried changing my MainController class to have a mapping for /service, previously it was just "/", and this did not help.

Code for MainController:

```
package com.example.photographygallerysite.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/service")
    public String start() {
        return "start";
    }



}
```

start references start.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photography by Oliver Johnson</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            background-color: rgb(255, 253, 247);
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1 {
            color: #333;
            margin-top: 50px;
            font-family: 'Corben', Georgia, Times, serif;
            color: rgb(38, 24, 24);
        }

        a {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            background-color: rgb(38, 24, 24);
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-radius: 2px;
            transition: background-color 0.3s;
            font-family: 'Nobile', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        a:hover {
            background-color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.55);
        }

        .slideshow-container {
            max-width: 750px;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
        }

        .mySlides {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            animation: fade 7s linear; /* Adjust the duration as needed */
        }

        @keyframes fade {
            0%, 5% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            5%, 95% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            99%, 100% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }

        .w3-badge {
            height: 13px;
            width: 13px;
            margin: 0 2px;
            background-color: #bbb;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            transition: background-color 0.6s;
        }

        .w3-badge-active {
            background-color: #4285f4;
        }

        /* Content separator styling */
        .separator {
            border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 57%;
            opacity: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Photography by Oliver Johnson</h1>

<div class="separator"></div>

<div class="slideshow-container w3-content w3-section">
    <div class="mySlides w3-animate-fading">
        <img src="http://ip:8080/images/firstImg.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides w3-animate-fading">
        <img src="http://ip:8080/images/DSC_0393.JPG" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides w3-animate-fading">
        <img src="http://ip:8080/images/DSC_0348.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides w3-animate-fading">
        <img src="http://ip:8080/images/DSC_0383.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="separator"></div>

<script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > slides.length) {
            myIndex = 1;
        }
        slides[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(carousel, 7000); // Adjust the timeout to match the animation duration
    }
</script>

<a href="http://ip:8080/displayAll">See all pictures</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Code for PhotographyGallerySiteApplication

```
package com.example.photographygallerysite;

import com.example.photographygallerysite.Model.Image;
import com.example.photographygallerysite.repo.ImageRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;


@SpringBootApplication
public class PhotographyGallerySiteApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private ImageRepository repo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PhotographyGallerySiteApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Image firstImg = new Image();
        firstImg.setFilename("firstImg.jpg");
        firstImg.setLocation("Hartlepool");
        firstImg.setCamera("Old Nikon");
        repo.save(firstImg);

        Image DSC_0393 = new Image();
        DSC_0393.setFilename("DSC_0393.JPG");
        DSC_0393.setLocation("Hartlepool");
        DSC_0393.setCamera("Old Nikon");
        repo.save(DSC_0393);

        Image DSC_0323 = new Image();
        DSC_0323.setFilename("DSC_0323.jpg");
        DSC_0323.setLocation("Hartlepool");
        DSC_0323.setCamera("Old Nikon");
        repo.save(DSC_0323);

        Image DSC_0332 = new Image();
        DSC_0332.setFilename("DSC_0332.jpg");
        DSC_0332.setLocation("Hartlepool");
        DSC_0332.setCamera("Old Nikon");
        repo.save(DSC_0332);

        Image DSC_0348 = new Image();
        DSC_0348.setFilename("DSC_0348.jpg");
        DSC_0348.setLocation("Hartlepool");
        DSC_0348.setCamera("Old Nikon");
        repo.save(DSC_0348);

        Image DSC_0368 = new Image();
        DSC_0368.setFilename("DSC_0368.jpg");
        DSC_0368.setLocation("Hartlepool");
        DSC_0368.setCamera("Old Nikon");
        repo.save(DSC_0368);

        Image DSC_0383 = new Image();
        DSC_0383.setFilename("DSC_0383.jpg");
        DSC_0383.setLocation("Hartlepool");
        DSC_0383.setCamera("Old Nikon");
        repo.save(DSC_0383);

        Image DSC_0389 = new Image();
        DSC_0389.setFilename("DSC_0389.jpg");
        DSC_0389.setLocation("Hartlepool");
        DSC_0389.setCamera("Old Nikon");
        repo.save(DSC_0389);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BIBOOunit1998X I am not really sure, we learnt how to use Spring MVC on my uni course, making spring boot websites with gradle, but never went as far as deploying them.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this tutorial on springboot regarding usage of jsp? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp

Answer (score 0):

try to use proper guideline for Spring boot REST API,
and nowadays we rarely use JSP with Spring Boot.

try to use some configuration
and try to post your `application.properties`
**add this lines if not there**

> spring.mvc.view.prefix=/jsp/

> spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

add `tomcat-embed-jasper` in `pom.xml`

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Comment: [Configuration for JSP](https://medium.com/@dsforgood/configuring-jsp-in-spring-boot-application-81ea7336a082)

you can refer this document

Comment: I forgot to mention that my project works fine on tomcat on my M2 Macbook with tomcat. I also don't have a pom.xml.